# Canvas toDataURL with CSS webkitFilter

Tags: javascript, css, html, canvas

I have applied a CSS filter to a canvas like so:

```
canvas.style.webkitFilter = 'hue-rotate(90deg)';
```

If I then try to download the content of the canvas using the download attribute of an anchor element:

```
var imgData = canvas.toDataURL('image/*');
link.download = 'Image';
link.href = imgData;
```

the downloaded image does not have the applied filter. Even if I use getImageData to just view the image data or try setting the source of an image to the image data the same problem occurs. Is there anyway in JavaScript to get the image data of a canvas with a CSS filter applied?

Comment: I don't think so, the css is manipulating the presentation of the canvas, not the data on the canvas itself, which is what the toDataURL method is retrieving

Comment: Did you find a solution for this question?

Answer (score 0):

**You can apply Hue-shift in canvas itself.**

For example, the CamanJS library has some nice image filters:  http://camanjs.com/

This is from their docs:

> Hue
>
> Adjusts the hue of the image. It can be used to shift the colors in an
>   image in a uniform fashion. The Range is 0 to 100.
>
> Sometimes, Hue is expressed in the range of 0 to 360. If that's the
>   terminology you're used to, think of 0 to 100 representing the
>   percentage of Hue shift in the 0 to 360 range.

Example code from CamanJS:

```
Caman("#image", function () {
      this.hue(90).render();
});
```